# When I'm move to the next frame the text box is still selected as3?

Tags: android, actionscript-3

I am doing a mental calculation game and it is the following the game consume in has the accounts to do and the user has to write with the keyboard in android the number until then I have now what I want to do is when I pass from level to Textinput is soon selected so that the users can only enter the numbers (I am also in doubt as to put only the numerical keyboard for andorid keyboards).

This is the game code:

```
            conta.restrict = "0-9\n";
            conta.maxChars = 3;
            conta.background = true;
            conta.backgroundColor = 0x4DFF67;
            conta.border = true; // Terá borda
            conta.borderColor = 0xFFCD70; // Cor da borda
            conta.text = "Nº";


            vala.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, tobias);

            function tobias(MouseEvent){
                if (conta.text == "12"){
                    trace("Acertou");
                    nextFrame();
                }else{
                    trace("Errou");
                    conta.text = "";
                    conta.backgroundColor = 0xFF4D40;
                }
            }

            conta.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, function(e:KeyboardEvent):void
            {
            if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER)
            {
                if (conta.text == "12"){
                    trace("Acertou");
                    nextFrame();
                }else{
                    trace("Errou");
                    conta.text = "";
                    conta.backgroundColor = 0xFF4D40;
                }
            }
            });
            conta.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, function(e:KeyboardEvent):void
            {
                if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER)
                {
                    conta.text = "";
                }
            });


            conta.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, clearBox);
            function clearBox(evt:FocusEvent):void
            {
                conta.text="";
            }
```

[Text Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eF3S8.png)

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#focus

Comment: Use StageText for Android/iOS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12086067/air-android-force-numeric-text-input